# Is there an army tank in any of the GTA 2 multiplayer maps?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-2

Me and some friends have started playing GTA 2 multiplayer. To get edge on them I've been looking around for the army tank. I know where they are in singleplayer, but I haven't been able to find them in multiplayer so far.

**Is there an army tank in any of the GTA2 multiplayer maps?**